# Iterate over json api and append results to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, urllib

I'm attempting to load Excel data into a Pandas DataFrame and then push the ip_address from the DataFrame to an api which returns information back in json format, and then append the results from the json back to the original DataFrame - how would I do this, iterating over each row in the dataframe and appending the results back each time?

Initial dataframe:

```
date | ip | name
date1 | ip1 | name1
date2 | ip2 | name2
```

json:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "8.8.8.8": {
        "proxy": "yes",
        "type": "VPN",
        "provider": "Google Inc",
        "risk": 66
    }
}
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_excel (r'test_data.xlsx')

def query_api(ip_address):
    risk_score = None
    vpn_score = None
    api_key = "xxx"
    base_url = "http://falseacc.com/"
    endpoint = f"{base_url}{ip_address}?key={api_key}&risk=1&vpn=1"
    r = requests.get(endpoint)
    if r.status_code not in range(200, 299):
        return None, None
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(endpoint) as url:
            data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
            proxy = (data[ip_address]['proxy'])
            type = (data[ip_address]['type'])
            risk = (data[ip_address]['risk'])
            df2 = pd.Dataframe({"ip":[ip_address],
                                "proxy":[proxy],
                                "type":[type],
                                "risk":[risk]})
            print(df2)
    except:
        print("No data")
```

Expected output:
Dataframe:

```
date | ip | name | proxy | type | risk
date1 | ip1 | name1 | proxy1 | type1 | risk1
date2 | ip2 | name2 | proxy2 | type2 | risk2
```

Comment: Does the API allow pushing multiple IPs at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the pandas  `Series.apply` method to pick each **ip** from your dataframe, and get the **proxy, type, risk** values corresponding to it from your `query_api` function. Then assign the values to the corresponding columns in the end:

```
df = pd.read_excel (r'test_data.xlsx')

def query_api(ip_address):
    risk_score = None
    vpn_score = None
    api_key = "xxx"
    base_url = "http://falseacc.com/"
    endpoint = f"{base_url}{ip_address}?key={api_key}&risk=1&vpn=1"
    r = requests.get(endpoint)
    if r.status_code not in range(200, 299):
        return pd.Series([None]*3)
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(endpoint) as url:
            data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
            proxy = (data[ip_address]['proxy'])
            type = (data[ip_address]['type'])
            risk = (data[ip_address]['risk'])
            return pd.Series([proxy, type, risk])
            
    except:
        return pd.Series([None]*3)


df[['proxy','type','risk']] = df.ip.apply(query_api)
```

Have a look at the official [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to know how `pandas.Series.apply` works.

I would also recommend to not use **type** as a variable name in your code since it overshadows the in-built `type` function in python

Comment: Thanks, I'm running into an error where trying to assign it back onto the original df: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ip'. Removing ip so it reads: df[['proxy','ip_type','risk']] = df.apply(query_api) - this then returns the dataframe as expected but the proxy/ip_type/risk columns are all "None"

Comment: Are you sure you have 'ip' as column in your dataframe as you posted in your question?

Comment: what is column name in dataframe where ip are stored?

Comment: Yes, sample return:         `date       ip   name proxy ip_type  risk
0 2021-01-01  8.8.8.8  tommo  None    None  None
1 2021-01-01  4.4.4.4   bexx  None    None  None
2 2021-01-01  8.8.8.8  saint  None    None  None`

Comment: do this:   `print (df.columns)`  in your original df. And tell the output here.

Comment: Ah sorry, it's called "ip" `Index(['date', 'ip', 'name'], dtype='object')`

Comment: Got it working, it was due to it being "Ip" and rather than "ip" - many thanks!